# User Browser Information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have one client requirement in which I need to group users according to the browser they have used to access the SharePoint website.

Also, I need to capture other browser parameters like browser name,version etc.

Suggest me some approaches to resolve this.

Thanks,
Joyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Browser name and version from javascript code like:

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if(tem!= null) return 'Opera '+tem[1];
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser

After the you can get the Current user using Javascript object model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = currentUser.get_id();
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

After getting user information, you can make a webApi call or server side call to store the data in your custom DB or other location.